# How can I add a universal keybinding for a program?

Tags: keybindings

I want to add a key binding that allows me to use it even when the application is not in the foreground. Specifically how would I add play/skip/previous key bindings to Spotify?

I'm not looking for the media key bindings. They can stay as is. I would like to add custom ones with keys of my choosing.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That's not even close to what I'm asking.

Comment: As written, it's too close to the duplicate. Your issue might not at all be duplicate - so an edit to this explaining specifically why this isn't a duplicate and linking to the post should be enough to review this and get it reopened. Perhaps you have a specific key combination you wish to bind? (or explicitly don't want to use the F7 through F9 alternate meanings?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be answered by [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167967/creating-system-wide-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-applications). Basically, you're going to want to create an Automator action and assign it a global shortcut using the Keyboard preferences panel.

Edit: @bmike , the dupe you referenced didn't answer his question. The one I linked to does.

Comment: Thanks jimmy0x52 - what's going to be best - picking the details from the answers you linked to or just closing this dupe of the other.

Comment: @bmike The accepted answer in that other thread is very elaborate - I'd suggest just pointing this at that thread and closing this one as a dupe.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That link is closer to a duplicate.