# OS X El Captain - Terminal shortcut is not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I defined a shortcut for opening a Terminal, but it isn't working.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please don't add answers to the question itself. Either accept the answer which helped you most (by clicking on the checkmark at the left) or post an answer yourself (and accept it).

Comment: Or, in this case, upvote the corresponding answer to the linked question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the shortcut you created is specific to the *Application*.

When you create the shortcut, you need to enter the "exact name of the menu command" within the Application specified in the dropdown above.

[image]

Typing "Terminal" won't work.

---

3 Options to quickly Launch Terminal

#### Add to your Dock

Open Your Applications Folder and simply drag the Terminal icon to your dock.  Click on it whenever you want.

[image]

#### Use Spotlight

One of my favorite ways to launch programs is to simply type it in Spotlight.  Press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> to invoke Spotlight and just start typing

[image]

#### Use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)

If you have to have a keyboard shortcut to run Terminal, consider using  [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).  It's free software that allows you create custom shortcuts for virtually any task.  Best of all, it's free.

Comment: but I didn't type "Terminal", I selected the 'Terminal.app' in the 'Application - select box'

Comment: There's no menu called "Terminal" in Terminal.  There's a Menu called "New Window with Same Settings" *within* Terminal, but you will have to be in Terminal to to have the keyboard shortcut recognized.

Comment: I solved it like this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167967/creating-system-wide-keyboard-shortcut-to-launch-applications

Comment: So, what Mateusz said.  You should upvote his answer if that worked.

Comment: @Allan - shouldn't he accept rather than upvote the answer?  Not that I expect he will - he never did seem to understand your answer, so he probably just doesn't care.

Comment: @MartyFried - If the answer worked for him, he *should* accept, but there's no rule that he *has to*. I'm not worried about it....

Answer (score 2):

Create a Service Automator workflow. Set it as no input and available from any application. Place there "Open Application" module and choose Terminal.app. Save it with the name like: "OpenTerminal".
Then in keyboard shortcuts preferences, select Services and look for "OpenTerminal" service -> assign Your shortcut there.

Comment: I'm on 10.11.6 and I've tried that method but my newly saved Automator Service does not show under the Services in the Shortcuts :(

Comment: Have You followed all the steps from this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167974/74657 ?

Comment: I didn't follow that link but I did try it with an Apple Script, but hey if that works then I'm very glad.

I tried the script below:
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    reopen
  end tell
  return input
end run