# System-wide shortcut to open a new window in Safari?

Tags: safari, automator, mojave

I'm trying to use Automator to create a system-wide shortcut to open a new Safari window. I'm using the method described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/167974/95690).

I can get Safari to open a specific url, for example by running

`$ open -a Safari "https://apple.stackexchange.com"`

From the command line. But this opens a new tab (not a new window) and requires specifying a URL.

Automator also has an "Internet > Display Webpages" action that has the same problems.

[image]

Is there a way to get Safari to open a new, blank window?

Comment: Try using a **Run AppleScrip**t _action_, replacing the default _code_, with: `tell application "Safari" to make new document`

Comment: Does it have to be in Automator? If not, this is easily accomplished in [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) where you could make a macro to activate Safari and then do ⌘N (or select the File » New Window menu), and then assign a keyboard shortcut for that.

Comment: Thanks, the AppleScript action worked brilliantly. I didn't try Keyboard Masetro but that product also looks impressive. Thank you both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Automator**, create a **Service** *workflow* (pre **macOS Mojave**), or a **Quick Action** *workflow* in **macOS Mojave**.

Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, replacing the default *code*, with:

```
tell application "Safari" to make new document
```

The above piece of **AppleScript** *code* by itself will open a new window in **Safari** however, it will not have focus. If you want the new window to have focus then use a `tell` *block*, e.g.:

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document
    activate
end tell
```

You can then assign a keyboard shortcut in the usual manner per information in the link within your question.

Comment: This is brilliant, but unfortunately in Catalina one needs to grant permissions to open Safari individually to each app that might happen to be open when the shortcut is triggered. Will update if I find a solution...

Comment: @AntonioFavata I've devised another way to avoid that error. See [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382449/362579).

Comment: That sounds brilliant, thanks @kubanczyk — I’ll try as soon as I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

This assumes that:

- Safari is configured **not** to open new pages in tabs
- Safari is the default browser.

### Howto

Press **Cmd-Space** then search and run **Automator**, create a **Quick Action** workflow (macOS Mojave and later, earlier that item was called 
*Service*).

Change the input method in the top right sidebar to **no input**.

Choose **Library** -> **Utilities** -> **Run AppleScript** action. Drag it to the main area. Replace the default code with:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return "https://www.google.com"
end run
```

Now a second action, choose **Library** -> **Internet** -> **Display Webpage**, drag it to the main area **below** the first action.

Press **Cmd-S** to save, name the workflow "Webpage".

Now go to **System properties** -> **Keyboard** -> **Shortcuts** -> **Services** -> scroll down to find your workflow/service called "Webpage". Press **Add shortcut**.

### Explanation

The contrived setup intends to avoid the problem with the first answer: "in Catalina one needs to grant permissions to open Safari individually to each app that might happen to be open when the shortcut is triggered".  Somehow the "Display Webpage" is not impacted by the permission system. The output of the first action becomes the input of the second action.

Comment: Sorry for not testing this until now. It works as advertised, thank you! (Although what I was _really_ after was a way to open a new window without any website...)

Comment: @AntonioFavata I googled "safari url for empty page" and it says to change `https://whatever` to `about:blank`

Comment: That's good thinking, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with the workflow, which produces a warning: `The action "Display Webpages" was not supplied with the required data.` Thanks for your continued efforts though :)

Answer (score 0):

Forget the hacks that will invariably break. Use an actual automation tool!

I use [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org) (free, open-source), and the following config (AppleScript taken from the answer above):

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt"}, "s", function()
  ok,result = hs.applescript([[
    tell application "Safari"
      make new document
      activate
    end tell
  ]])
end)
```